# How do I remove the rights to view the channel from the team author? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to make a team **!test**.

Those who use this command are taken away the rights to view the channel **#channel_test**

**My code:**

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(" ");
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  let discussionChannel = client.channels.cache.get("808068114981978152");

  if (message.member.roles.cache.has("838776329176088586")) {
    if (command === "test") {
      discussionChannel.rolePermissions('838776329176088586').remove('VIEW_CHANNEL: true')
      discussionChannel.updateOverwrite(message.member, { VIEW_CHANNEL: false })
      client.channels.cache.get("776012673879244840").send("Good")
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems like you're accessing a role and then modifying the role itself instead of each individual user, is that what you intended?

Comment: I want the user to write a command, and he can no longer see the channel

Comment: Are you first checking to see if the user using the command has the "Tester" role?

Comment: YES, I'm checking the role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to slightly change the method you are using `rolePermissions` (which actually doesn't exist), with the [`updateOverwrite`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=updateOverwrite) method instead.

Assuming that `discussionChannel` is a `TextChannel` object, then you can simply replace your statement of:

```js
discussionChannel.rolePermissions('838776329176088586').remove('VIEW_CHANNEL: true')
```

with this:

```js
discussionChannel.updateOverwrite(message.member, { VIEW_CHANNEL: false });
```

For more information regarding writing permissions for channels, feel free to check the [Discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#adding-overwrites).

Comment: (node:26185) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: discussionChannel is not defined

Comment: You need to define the `discussionChannel` like I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: In order to do that, you'll have to do something around the lines of `let discussionChannel = client.channels.cache.get("channel ID here");`

Comment: You should remove one of the statements like I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Are you still getting that `ReferenceError`?